# Discover version of Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

How can I know what's the Bluetooth version of my Android device?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126512/how-to-find-android-bluetooth-version-android

Comment: yeah man, i found it too. But I want to discover what is my bluetooth version to check if it is capable to connect in large distances.

Comment: differ in distance is due to bluetooth class not version (A, B and C) take a look here to read more about bluetooth:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I have a samsung Galaxy S2 here is a method to get info on your bluetooth version**

1. Turn on bluetooth by going to the home screen, clicking menu->settings bluetooth.  Pull that to enabled.  Make sure it is on.
2. On the home screen, click  menu -> settings -> applications -> 'ALL' tab.
3. Select: "Bluetooth".
4. A screen pops up with information about the program.

Comment: Following these directions there is still nothing show on my Samsung Galaxy S3 from Straight Talk. 4.1.2 Android but no idea about Bluetooth version.

Answer (score 6):

Go to http://www.gsmarena.com/ and search for your device: the site provides several info including Bluetooth version.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried several searches for finding the Bluetooth settings on my LGL15G with no luck finding a solution that will get the answer on my phone.

I did find the information.

I searched for LG L15G Sunrise Specifications on Google

I went to a link called http://www.lg.com/mobile

I used the top of the page search for LG L15G

It gave me one result, which I clicked on:

http://www.lg.com/us/cell-phones/lg-L15G-sunrise

I clicked on Tech Specs and searched the page for Bluetooth.  It took me to

Bluetooth® Version  4.0

My point is, there doesn't appear to be a way to find the Bluetooth version, at least on many devices, but if you can find a manual on line, it might be in there.  If someone comes up with a way to actually find it on the device, let us know.

Answer (score -1):

**Menu** > **Settings** > under device, **Application Manager** > swipe to **All** > click on **Bluetooth Share** > **version** would be displayed under app info.

Comment: the OP wanted to know what version of Bluetooth they have, not what version of Bluetooth Share they have, which is what you get when you follow the advice given here. Bad advice is worse than none at all, I see this time and again in forums ppl wanting to give an answer at all costs so that they look like the big expert, and all they give is add to confusion, if you don't know what you are talking about just keep schtum.

Answer (score -3):

Go to Settings>More...>Application Manager>All
Click on Bluetooth Share
version will appear below the heading "Bluetooth Share"